# Wheel Widget is Weird When I Generate Rig using Rigacar Addon

Tags: add-on

I named all the empties correctly and the bones were all fine. But when I click generate rig, the front right wheel widget is really big. How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: This is a Q&A site for problems with Blender and its built-in addons only. Rigacar is a third-party addon and therefore you'll need to ask the author directly.   Having said that, if all the other wheels are correct, I'd suggest checking the scale and origin of the wheel that is giving problems against the other 3.